# C# array to javascript array

Tags: javascript, c#, json, html, google-visualization

I have two method in my code behind one returns an int array and the other returns string array.
I want to use these two array to populate the google chart data table.

I do not have any experience with Json or AJAX however I found a relatively simple solution using the string.Join and eval to convert the string to an array.

I have managed to do this with the int array however I found a problem with the string array. I know that the problem is that I need to add '' to each  element in the array.

```
function drawChart() {

    var locality = ['Loc_A', 'Loc_B', 'Loc_C', 'Loc_D', 'Loc_E'];
    //var locality =  eval('[<% =string.Join(", ", locations)%>]');
    var frequency = eval('[<% =string.Join(", ", numbers ) %>]'); 

    var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
    data.addColumn('string', 'locality');
    data.addColumn('number', 'frequency');

    for (i = 0; i < locality.length; i++)
        data.addRow([locality[i], frequency[i]]);

    var options = {
         title: 'Test'
     };

    var chart = new google.visualization.PieChart(document.getElementById('piechart'));
    chart.draw(data, options);
}
```

I need to adjust the commented line by adding '' with each word so that then I can convert the string to a javascript array.

Any ideas or any other hints howto convert c# arrays  from code behing to java script arrays. Code examples would be very helpful please.

Comment: not sure if I am following you but could you now use a `var options = new List<T> {  "Test"};` for example and if you want to populate the List<T> you can implement the List<T>.Add() Method.. your var options would be a good example of C# List<T>

Comment: Just use `System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer` to serialize .NET objects to JSON. And use `JSON.parse()` instead of `eval`.

Comment: What you want to do is to convert your C# data to JSON.  I don't know C#, but I assume there are functions to convert various C# sources to JSON for you.  Perhaps this will help: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb412179(VS.100).aspx

Comment: Unfortunately I have never used Json and I would need a code example with explanation to understand.

Comment: do a google search and start to learn / understand what `JSON` is .. it's not that difficult.. I have never used is not a valid excuse by the way.. try to expand your horizons respectfully speaking

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**METHOD 1:** Chart data formatiing in drawChart()

using System.Web.Script.Serialization;

1) Build jsonobj

```
public string GetLocality()
    {
        string[] locality = new string[] { "Loc_A", "Loc_B", "Loc_C", "Loc_D", };
        //long[] frequency = new long[] { 10, 20, 10, 80 };
        JavaScriptSerializer jsSerializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
        string jsonobj = jsSerializer.Serialize(locality);
        return jsonobj;       
    }
```

2) Either Add this in HTML data-attribute or pull using ajax call.

```
   <div id="piechart" data-piechart-localityary='<ServerSide call/var Getlocality()'> 
   <div>
```

3) pull in data in your javascript from html data-dash as

```
var locality = $('#piechart').data('piechart-localityary');
```

---

**Method 2:** Chart data formatting in code behind

I would recommend to keep DrawChart() function simple. You mentioned you have the Arrays available in code behind.

1) Build the JavaScript string literal object in code behind. 
[Format](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/reference#dataparam)
2) Either attached jSonData into html page as data-attribute or pull it using ajax. I'll recommend saving a server round-trip if not crucial. 
3) Get this data into drawChart() from html-data-dash
4) Working example [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/neolok/57y3dc11/1/) with source code

```
function drawChart() {

//var jsonData = $('#piechart').data('piechar-jsonobj');
var jsonData =  
{
"cols":[
    {"label":"Locality","type":"string"},
    {"label":"Frequency","type":"number"}
       ],
"rows":[
    {"c":[{"v":"Loc_A","f":null},{"v":10.00,"f":null}]},
    {"c":[{"v":"Loc_B","f":null},{"v":20.00,"f":null}]},
    {"c":[{"v":"Loc_C","f":null},{"v":10.00,"f":null}]},
    {"c":[{"v":"Loc_D","f":null},{"v":80.00,"f":null}]}
       ]
} ;

var data = new google.visualization.DataTable(jsonData);


var options = {
    title: 'MyPieChart',
    backgroundColor: { fill: 'transparent' },
    is3D: true
};

var chart = new google.visualization.PieChart(document.getElementById('piechart'));
chart.draw(data, options);
} 
google.load("visualization", "1", {packages:["corechart"]}); 
google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);
```

Code to build JavaScript string literal object

```
 public class Graph
{
    public List<ColInfo> cols { get; set; }
    public List<DataPointSet> rows { get; set; }    
}

public class ColInfo
{

    public string label { get; set; }
    public string type { get; set; }
}

public class DataPointSet
{
    public List<DataPoint> c { get; set; }
}

public class DataPoint
{
    public string v { get; set; } // value    
    public string f { get; set; } // format
}

public string DemoPieChart()
    {
        Graph ChartData = new Graph();
        ChartData.cols = new List<ColInfo>();
        ChartData.rows = new List<DataPointSet>();
        ColInfo Col1 = new ColInfo();
        Col1.label = "Locality";
        Col1.type = "string";
        ColInfo Col2 = new ColInfo();
        Col2.label = "Frequency";
        Col2.type = "number";
        ChartData.cols.Add(Col1);
        ChartData.cols.Add(Col2);

        //Loop your data entry from both array
        string[] locality = new string[] { "Loc_A", "Loc_B", "Loc_C", "Loc_D", };
        long[] frequency = new long[] { 10, 20, 10, 80 };

        for (int i = 0; i < locality.Length; i++)
        {
            DataPointSet Row = new DataPointSet();
            Row.c = new List<DataPoint>();
            DataPoint p1 = new DataPoint();
            p1.v = locality[i];
            p1.f = null;

            DataPoint p2 = new DataPoint();
            p2.v =  frequency[i].ToString("F")  ;           
            p2.f = null;
            Row.c.Add(p1);
            Row.c.Add(p2);
            ChartData.rows.Add(Row);          
        }
        JavaScriptSerializer jsSerializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
        string jsonobj = jsSerializer.Serialize(ChartData);           
        return jsonobj;
      }
```

Hope this helps you build your solution. In case you need clarification or specific code add comments. I build html using razor (MVC) to populate data-attributes.

---

Possible issue: JavaScriptSerializer adds quote around numbers.

```
{"c":[{"v":"Loc_A","f":null},{"v": "10.00" ,"f":null}]}
```

Notice "10.00" instead of 10.00. GoogleCharts doesn't like it. It might not draw chart or draw a incorrect chart.

Comment: Yes very helpful, what it is not clear referring to method 1 is how the jsonobj is mapped to the a column of the pie chart and how it is traversed to draw the chart because I guess I cannot use a for loop like i did in my code (shown when I asked the question).

Comment: For loop should be fine. See this [ForLoopedPieChart](http://jsfiddle.net/neolok/nt2g5hwj/2/). I used your code with for loop just hard-coded the frequency. You may be entering your frequency (number) with quotes into googleapi. You can debug your javascript and see what data is (1) getting in frequency var and (2) what data is your drawchart sending into googleapi. If your data is like var frequencyQ your charts wont get plotted.

Answer (score 1):

This should do it:

```
    using System.Web.Script.Serialization;

    public static string SerializeListAsJsonData<T>(List<T> list)
    {
        JavaScriptSerializer jsSerializer = new JavaScriptSerializer()
        {
            //MaxJsonLength = _maxJsonLength, <-- This is optional (used for large lists)
        };

        return jsSerializer.Serialize(list);
    }
```

The method takes a List of objects and serializes a JSON string for you. This string you can do a JSON.parse() on, then you can freely access the objects in JavaScript. You specifically requested something for C# arrays, but I recommend sticking to lists (if you need a string array then just make a List of strings).

```
List<string> list = new List<string>();
list.add("A");
list.add("B");
list.add("C");
list.add("D");
list.add("E");

string jsonString = SerializeListAsJsonData(list); // <-- jsonString is what you send to your JavaScript.
```

Or like this if you somehow need to keep your string array:

```
 string[] stringArray = { "A", "B", "C", "D", "E" };
 string jsonString = SerializeListAsJsonData(stringArray.ToList<string>()); // <-- jsonString is what you send to your JavaScript
```

Comment: Cannot understand what this does but what I am trying to achieve is to pass this array "    public string[] locations = { "A", "B", "C", "D", "E" };" which is in the code behind to the function data.AddColumn(); in the aspx page

Comment: Edited answer to make such an array.

Comment: Ok then all need is to pass the string to the javascript in the aspx page. data.AddColumn('string', jsonString); like so right? Tks

Comment: First: var something = JSON.parse(jsonString)...then: something[0] will yield 'A'. So data.AddColumn('string', something[0]) maybe...haven't worked with those mentioned data tables before, so just try and see.